# Confusion over Java HashMap createEntry method

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to understand the inner implementation of HashMap in Java. I have a confusion with the 'createEntry' method.

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    size++;
}
```

it creates an entry object 'e' and then it puts it to another entry object and stores it into the bucket[bucketindex] and it also stores the key and value. I am not able to understand the purpose of creation of the Entry object 'e' here. Could someone please explain.

Regards

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable#Separate_chaining

Comment: `table[bucketIndex]` doesn't *create* an entry. It *gets* the entry that is stored in `table`, at the `bucketIndex` index. This is a simple linked list, where the new node becomes the first node of the list.

Comment: (Note that the OpenJDK8 code is very different.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gets the previous entry in the bucket (even if it is `null`). It then creates a new entry, setting its `next` entry to that previous one retrieved. It then sets the new entry to the same index in the bucket.

So say you had 3 element in hash

```
0: [null]
1: [some entry]
2: [null]
```

And you had to add to index 1

```
0: [null]
1: [new entry] -> [some entry]
2: [null]
```

Similarly, adding to index 0

```
0: [newer entry] -> [null]
1: [new entry] -> [some entry]
2: [null]
```